# Coin Change algorithm for a limited coin?

Tags: algorithm, sum, combinations, coin-change

My program is tasked to count all possible combinations of getting the value of T, with a list of coins with varying (and some identical) values with limited amount of coins.

Two coins with different names could have a same value, for example both "Gold" and "Topaz" coins both have a value of 3.

```
public static int change(int target, ArrayList<GemCoin> coinStocks) {
    int[] combi = new int[target + 1];
    combi[0] = 1;
    for (GemCoin g: coinStocks) {
        for (int i = 1; i < combi.length; i++) {
            if (i >= g.getValue() && g.getStocks() > 0) {  ///if
                combi[i] += combi[i - d.getChips()];
            }
        }
    }
    for(int im : combi){
        System.out.println(im);
    }
    return combi[target];
}
```

That's my general idea, but i do notice that the coin stocks "ran out" before reaching the last index in combi, even though there exists a combination involving that coin.

Comment: You say your function should return a list of combinations, but it returns a single integer.  Please could you provide some sample input and the desired output

Comment: i'm sorry, "how many" combinations

Comment: for example, Topaz (T) Coin is $1, Ruby (R) Coin is $1, Sapphire(S) Coin is $2, Gold(G) Coin is $3. There are 4 Topaz, 1 Ruby, 1 Sapphire and 1 Gold. The target  is $4.                                      To get that you can use 4T/3T1R/2T1S/1G meaning 4 is returned as output

Comment: Could you post the code for your GemCoin class?

Comment: There are 6 combinations: 4T, 3T1R, 2T1S, 1T1R1S, 1T1G, 1R1G.

Comment: Where does d.getChips() come from? If the quantity is a property of the GemCoin class then your algorithm doesn't work as intended. If not then it can work with a minor modification, but it wouldn't give you the desired result, e.g. 4T and a target of 3 would give you 4 as answer and not 1, because you treat each coin as unique, even if they are all T.